# AWS ELB is dropping traffic

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elb

I am facing a lack of traffic between my ELB server and Hosts Machines.

> At ELB :- total traffic logs count in 1 hour- 1123567
>
> And at Nginx :- total traffic count in 1 hour- 1051233

There are 10 machines behind this ELB and the above Nginx traffic count is sum of all 10 hosts.

There is a port forwarding rule on ELB :-

```
80 --> 3000
443 --> 3000
3000 --> 3000
```

We have a NodeJs application running on all 10 hosts on 3000 port.

Comment: How did you obtain the ELB statistics? It might be invalid traffic requests from automated bots. You can [turn on access logs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-access-logs.html) for the load balancer to obtain more information.

Comment: Downloaded all the files from s3 ELB log bucket. and uses `cat elb.log| wc -l`. @JohnRotenstein

Comment: If you have the Load Balancer logs and the NGINX logs, you could try to match them up to figure out what records have disappeared. Do it by time range (eg the first hour) to make things easier.

Comment: I already did, and I filter the urls with are not available at my host machines. But I wanted to know how the url is dropped between ELB to Hosts.

Comment: Do you have a sample of a request that hit the ELB but did not get to NGINX? Was there any pattern to the requests that were dropped?

Comment: Please find the logs sample with the link.[link](http://www.beetxt.com/wAf/)@JohnRotenstein